# What does it mean if a repo has one license and the files have other license statements?

Tags: licensing

I found a [certain repository on GitHub](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder) that contains a `LICENSE.txt` file with an MIT license dated 2014, but in one of the source files, the top of the file contains an Apache 2.0 license dated 2013.

This specific instance isn't that important, it's just illustrating my question, but what sort of implications does this have for licensing? Does the license on individual files override the license placed on the whole project? Does the date on the license have any effect?

Comment: *Not a lawyer*, but I would take this to mean that the files are under the "repo license" **unless** it has a specific license embedded into the file.

Comment: No @DocBrown. I think you are correct. You just failed to mention that only the files that have licenses embedded into them would be dual licensed.

Comment: @RubberDuck: opposed to what you wrote in your first comment, I would not expect files with an embedded license not beeing also under the "repo's license". I would expect that both licenses apply, and one has to follow the terms of *both* licenses for those files in stake. In this specific case, this may indeed mean to follow the terms of the Apache license, but that's not true in general.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant @DocBrown. I apologize for not writing an answer in the comments.

Comment: In practice, it practically always means that the person changed the license in one place, **but forgot to make the change in other places**. As simple as that. The legal implications of that is indeed a different (and perfectly valid) question.

Comment: @RubberDuck: ok, I think I got what you meant, changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MainMa: that may be indeed the cause for the situation, and IANAL, but my common sense tells me in court the terms written down and published are the terms which count, if those terms are there intentionally or unintentionally is not significant as long as the error is not extremely obvious.

Comment: @MainMa I also think that that's what happened here since the Apache license is data 2013 and the license on the repo is dated 2014. But like DocBrown said, I think a court would go off of what's actually there and not what you think is supposed to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed have more than one license in place, at the same time, and either give the user of the code some freedom to pick the license he likes best (see [dual- or multi-licensing on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing)), or require him to obey the terms of both licenses, as long as they do not contain contradicting requirements.

A popular model is to have one license for a "work as a whole" (containing many source files), and different licenses for individual source code files, as long as the license for the individual source file is more permissive than the license for the work as a whole. For example, the GPL is a license where the text explicitly mentions it applies to the "work as a whole". That is why the Linux kernel is under GPL, but some kernel modules contain files which are under MIT or a modified BSD license. So as long as you use or publish those files individually, and not as part of the Linux kernel, you only have to follow the terms of the MIT or BSD license.

In your specific case, I would expect the MIT license has to be applied to the "work as a whole", and the combined MIT & Apache 2.0 for the files which contain the Apache license. The latter one is - at least slightly - *less* permissive than the MIT license. For example, the Apache license requires you to mention changes to the original code. IANAL, but such a term does not seem to contradict the MIT license. For example, when you change the file with the Apache license embedded, I would expect you have to mention those changes. When you change a different file, I would expect you are not required to do so. There are more differences between the two like a patent clause in the Apache license which is not part of the MIT license. So what you will actually have to check is if your intended usage of the code confirms to both licenses. And if you are not sure, ask a lawyer.